# Replacing a function with something iterable

Tags: python, recursion, yield

In short. How do I write something else than this: `for another in combinationOfK(K-1, L[i+1:]):` My function combinationOfK(...) is not iterable.

I am trying to understand the code from [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/99%20Prolog%20Problems%20Solutions#Problem_26:_Generate_the_combinations_of_K_distinct_objects_chosen_from_the_N_elements_of_a_list), solution to. `Problem 26: Generate the combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list`
I know what yield does. But I am trying to *write the code without* a `yield` statement. Code *with yield statement*  is this.

```
def combination(K, L):
    if K<=0:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(len(L)):
        thisone = L[i:i+1]
        for another in combination(K-1, L[i+1:]):
            yield thisone + another
```

[The question, `yield-keyword-explained`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/237028#237028) gave me the idea that I could replace yield. The recepie they give, which is not working for me, is:

> When you see a function with `yield` statements,  apply this easy
>   trick to understand what will happen:
>
> 1. Insert a line `result = []` at the start of the function.
> 2. Replace each `yield expr` with `result.append(expr)`.
> 3. Insert a line `return result` at the bottom of the function.
> 4. Yay - no more `yield` statements! Read and figure out code.
> 5. Revert function to original definition.

---

Using this to get code without yield give me this. The code is not working (the function is not iterable). *What do I have to write to get this code working without yield?*

```
def combinationOfK(K,L):
    result = []
    if K <= 0:
        result.append([])
        return
    for i in range(len(L)):
        thisone = L[i:i+1]
        for another in combinationOfK(K-1, L[i+1:]):  # the error
            result.append(thisone + another)
    return result
```

I am using this code to test the function,

```
the_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print list(combinationOfK(2, the_list))
```

raising error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Comment: You forgot to indent the 5th line in your last function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your original code uses `return` in an unusual way.

```
def combination(K, L):
    if K<=0:
        yield []
        return    #  <--- hmmm
```

Most of the time you won't see `return` in a generator, because you don't often need it. Usually, generators simply "fall off" at the end; the interpreter reaches the end of the generator without encountering a `return` statement, and then it knows to throw `StopIteration`.

In *this* case, the writer of the code has inserted a `return` statement to "hurry up" the process. When `K <= 0`, there's no more work to be done, so the generator can throw `StopIteration` -- but without the `return` statement, it would go into the `for` loop, producing incorrect results. In my opinion, a clearer way to do this would have been like so:

```
def combination(K, L):
    if K<=0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(len(L)):
            thisone = L[i:i+1]
            for another in combination(K-1, L[i+1:]):
                yield thisone + another
```

Now the conversion works as expected:

```
def combination2(K, L):
    result = []
    if K <= 0:
        result.append([])
    else:
        for i in range(len(L)):
            thisone = L[i:i + 1]
            for another in combination2(K - 1, L[i + 1:]):
                result.append(thisone + another)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

As Vincent mentioned, your function is returning None because of the 5th line. Change it to this:

```
def combinationOfK(K,L):
    result = []
    if K <= 0:
        result.append([])
        return result
    for i in range(len(L)):
        thisone = L[i:i+1]
        for another in combinationOfK(K-1, L[i+1:]):  # the error
            result.append(thisone + another)
    return result
```

However, why are you against yield? Generators make for readable, efficient code. The point of the Yield Keyword Explained article was not to dispense with it, but rather, to explain it.

In the generator code you posted:

```
def combination(K, L):
    if K<=0:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(len(L)):
        thisone = L[i:i+1]
        for another in combination(K-1, L[i+1:]):
            yield thisone + another
```

The `return` statement does NOT mean the same thing as `return` does in a normal function. In a generator, `return` immediately raises StopIteration, which causes the caller to stop iterating over the generator object.